# Check if record in localStorage added 1 minute ago

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check if the localStorage value is older than 1 minute:

```
var minute = 60*1000;
var savedtime = window.localStorage.getItem('eiTS');
var realtime = ((new Date) - savedtime);

if (window.localStorage.getItem('eiTS') === null) {
    window.localStorage.setItem('eiTS', new Date());
} else {
    if (realtime < minute) {
        console.log('expired');
    } else {
        console.log(savedtime);
    console.log('ok');
    }
}
```

But always get Ok in my console instead of expired if it is older than 1 minute. Can you please help me to find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed the task by tweaking the code with following:

```
var oneminute = 60 * 1000;
var savedtime = window.localStorage.getItem('eiTS');
var difference = (new Date() - new Date(savedtime) ) / oneminute;

if (savedtime === null) {
    window.localStorage.setItem('eiTS', new Date());
} else {
    if (difference < 1) {
} else {
    window.localStorage.removeItem('eiTS');
}
}
```

If any one may face the same problem please use the solution above.

Answer (score 0):

Please convert the realtime in to number and try. As per your logic issue is in below line of code.

```
 if (realtime < minute) {
```

First print the value of realtime and see. then try to convert to number and see.

Comment: Hi @DJara can you please show on the example how to achieve your suggestion. Thank you in advance.